# Javascript is called in IE but not in Chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have this code in my page

```
<script language="JavaScript" defer>totCb["19782"] = 2;</script>
```

I call this almost in the end of the script, this should add the new value to the array `totCb`. This works in IE but not in Chrome or FF, why?

Comment: Please provide a more complete code snippet. There is not enough information in the question to answer it. http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com are useful tools for this.

Comment: Does the variable `totCb` exist before this line of code?

Comment: yes, the variable exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what doctype you're using, but [in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer):

> The defer and async attributes must not be specified if the src attribute is not present.

Answer (score 0):

The language attribute is deprecated in favor of the type attribute. Instead try specifying it as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
  totCb["19782"] = 2;
</script>
```

[According to w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp), `defer` is only supported by IE.

Comment: w3schools.com is **NOT** a reference and is not affiliated in anyway to the w3c. More info : http://w3fools.com/ This information is a good example of why you should never quote w3schools.com. The defer attribute is supported by Firefox since the version 3.5 which was launched more than 1 year ago.

Answer (score -1):

IE is the only browser that supports the defer "attribute" in the script tag.

Comment: That's just not true. Firefox supports it as well. Even if it were true, other browsers would just ignore the attribute.